# Can QAF @datafile be parametrized?

Tags: qaf

Is it possible to parametrize @datafile in QAF BDD2?
I have the following line in my cucumber feature file

```
  @dataFile:src/test/resources/testdata.xls
```

I'd like to be able to use different test data files depending on the environment I run the test in. So I'll have

```
@dataFile:src/test/resources/env1_testdata.xls
```

of one environment and

```
@dataFile:src/test/resources/env2_testdata.xls
```

for another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as per [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#parameters-in-meta-value), You can use any property in value of meta-data for data provider. It will get resolved using configuration manager. You can utilize this feature as per your convenience. Below are few examples:

```
#example 1: file with env prefix
@dataFile:src/test/resources/${env.name}_testdata.xls 
#example 2: directory with env name
@dataFile:src/test/resources/${env.name}/testdata.xls
#example 3: sheet with env name
@dataFile:src/test/resources/testdata.xls @sheetName:${env.name}
#example 4: data table with env name
@dataFile:src/test/resources/testdata.xls @key:${env.name}
#example 5: multiple parameters
@dataFile:src/test/resources/${env.name}_testdata_${env.default.locale}.xls
```

in above examples, the first one assumes file with env prefix, second example assumes directory with env name, and the third one is sheet in data file with env name. Provided `env.name=qa` actual values will be resolved as

```
@dataFile:src/test/resources/qa_testdata.xls 
@dataFile:src/test/resources/qa/testdata.xls
@dataFile:src/test/resources/testdata.xls @sheetName:qa
@dataFile:src/test/resources/testdata.xls @key:qa
```

Related documentation:

- [Parameters in meta-value](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#parameters-in-meta-value)
- [Make test data driven](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html)
- [Different ways of providing properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html)

Comment: Thank you! I added env.name=TEST_ENV to resources/application.properties file and it is working perfectly!

Comment: user861594, Do you know if it's possible to set env.name dynamically in the code, or as an environment variable?

Comment: It's a property. refer documentation for [different ways of providing properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html). If you want to set using code you can use `setProperty` method. For example, `ConfigurationManager.getBundle().setProperty("propname", val); `